# Why does the time on my laptop keep changing?

Tags: windows, anti-virus, time

My Laptop time is changing when ever I am opening it first time of the day. 
This problem i notice since this new year 2018. 
I am using Antivirus - Kaspersky Internet Security with valid key and updated time to time. 
I am using Windows 7 Ultimate and my laptop is DELL Inspiron 4010.
However I have used this following technique to fix it, but still the problem is not fixed.

Steps I followed:

1. Go to start
2. Type task and hit enter
3. Click the arrow on the left next to task scheduler Library
4. Click the arrow next to Microsoft
5. Click the arrow next to windows
6. Click the folder Time Synchronize
7. At the top right click Synchronize
8. Click properties
9. Go down and check run with the highest privileges
10. Click the triggers tab at the top
11. Double click the trigger that is listed in the box
12. At the top Begin task at start up
13. Uncheck delay task
14. Check repeat task (change to 5 min)
15. On the right hand side change duration of indefinitely
16. Click OK twice
17. Exit Task Scheduler
18. Power off the computer

Comment: I have similar issue in one of my laptops, did you checked CMOS battery?

Comment: What does it keep changing to? Describe the problem as well as your solution.

Comment: Mostly I open my laptop in between 10am to 12 pm. But i have noticed at that time my laptop showing time around 1am - 3 am. I checked my time zone even, it's in place.
My Internet time is also been auto updated to Windows.time website

Comment: Should i change my CMOS battery? 
I bought my laptop 5 years back.

Comment: it sounds like it is possible it is CMOS battery, I would suggest trying to leave your laptop for night with connected charger, If the date stays accurate then it means that it is most likely CMOS battery, which ran out of juice and is no longer able to keep the date.

Comment: @vakus I found out that my CMOS battery is totally dead. Still, I've not changed the battery. Anyway I am updating my time whenever i open my laptop from the command prompt, for Windows - w32tm /resync

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a possible CMOS battery issue.
You can confirm this by leaving your laptop over night with connected charger. If the date stays accurate then this means it is most likely CMOS batter.

This happens due to battery no longer being able to store enough charge to keep the [RTC clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_clock). When the laptop is left on charge then the RTC clock will be powered using the power supply.

In some laptop (and most PCs) replacing the CMOS battery is easy, as it is coin battery. Unfortunately in most of the laptops CMOS battery comes packed with wires which may make it harder to replace. If you are skilled with electronics you potentially could make your own replacement, but this may not be recommended. You may find cheap replacement batteries online on websites like ebay, but make sure that it contains the same amount of pins.